# How would I query SHA256 in bytea in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sha256

I get some data and create a SHA256 hash of the data. I store the hash (bytea) and an UUID in the database. When new data comes in, I want to find the corresponding UUID. I don't want to use the SHA256 as a key for storage size reasons (256bit vs 128bit). The UUID is then used as a primary key in other tables.

What would be the best index for

```
SELECT uuid FROM lookup WHERE hash=<SHA256>;
```

Is there a performant way to do this in Postgres or should I use something else for the lookup?

Comment: `create index on lookup(hash)`

Comment: What index type would that use? Or would it automatically use the best index type for the data type?

Comment: That's a b-tree index [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html)

Comment: Ok, and btree is the best index type for bytea? Or is it hash?